# Stop IDE from showing constant values

Tags: go, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

How can I make JetBrains GoLand IDE to stop showing me inline constant values?

[image]

I've tried to search it in the setting, in the help menu, and also ask Google (and chat), but didn't even know how to call it.

It is honestly one of the most useless and annoying features they added (IMO, I'm sure it has some good benefits, but I can't see it right now lol)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable inlay hints from the preferences menu.

`Preferences (command + ,)` -> `Editor` -> `Inlay Hints` -> `Values` -> uncheck `Go`

[image: Editor -> Inlay hints]